# How to find the debug run details for Azure Synapse Analytics in Azure Synapse logs?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-synapse

There are activity runs, Integration pipeline runs in Azure Synapse logs. But how can we get the logs for Debug activity runs for pipelines and data flows From Azure Synapse logs?

This is to get the total debug duration from logs?
[image]

I tried querying logs but I cannot find any in above tables for debug runs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the below tables?

SynapseIntegrationPipelineRuns | where Category == "DataFlow"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/monitoring/how-to-monitor-using-azure-monitor#logs

[image: synapseintegration]

[image: workspace-levellogs]

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did. Technically debug information is not there. that is a fact